# Summation using previous sum inside the sigma

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation, recurrence-relations

I'm doing a summation, but I need the current sum to be a part of the computation in the actual sigma. First I define $n$ and $\delta\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{50}2n+\delta$$

where $\delta$ is the current sum for each $n$.
So to avoid confusion the actual computation that I want is the following:

$$
\begin{split}
2\cdot1+0&=2\\
2\cdot2+2&=6\\
2\cdot3+6&=12\\
2\cdot4+12&=20\\
2\cdot5+20&=30\\
2\cdot6+30&=42\\
2\cdot7+42&=56\\
2\cdot8+56&=72\\
2\cdot9+72&=90\\\text{etc..}
\end{split}
$$

You see the previous summation are the $\delta$ in the next summation. As a side note: After just plugging in these numbers in OEIS, I found out that they are the pronic numbers, $a(n) = n\cdot(n+1).$ However, I could have used a totally different example. My question asks wether there is a notation for the sigma summation to get $\delta$ regardless of the outcome?

One idea I have is to use two sigmas instead of one, but I do not want to overcomplicate things if there is a better way..

(Im not necessarily interested in the result of the above computation, only in the process of how the notation works on how to compute)

***Update:*** After some answers and comments, my question can be addressed more clearly:

Is the following notation
$$a_k = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k}2n+a_{n-1}$$
a valid one?

Comment: es, that notation is perfectly valid - that's exactly how I've seen similar things written.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

What you actually are defining is the sequence $a_n$ which satisfies the initial condition $a_0=0$ and recurrence relation $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2n$. Can you now solve it?

**UPDATE**

I am saying that if you define your function as I am suggesting, $a_0 = \delta$ and
$$
\begin{split}
a_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n 2k + a_0 \\
    &= 2\sum_{k=1}^n k \\
    &= 2 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
    &= n(n+1).
\end{split}
$$

That the formula $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ holds can be proven by noticing that the sum
$$
1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + (n-2) +(n-1)+n
$$
can be grouped into pairs, adding first and last elements together, then second and next-to-last, etc. Each such pair has a sum of $n+1$ and

- if $n$ is even, there are exactly $n/2$ such pairs, so the sum is $(n+1)n/2$
- if $n$ is odd, there are $(n-1)/2$ such pairs and the middle number is $(n+1)/2$, so the sum is
  $$
  \frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{2} + \frac{n+1}{2}
   = \frac{n+1}{2} \left[(n-1)+1\right]
   = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
  $$

Comment: No. Im not used to mathematical notation. Are you saying that $$\sum_{n=1}^{50}a_i=2n+a_{i-1}$$ is allowed? And also is $a_{i-1}$ always initially 0?

Comment: oops. should be $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ instead of $i$.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy see update

Answer (score -1):

Doubly, or triply, (or *morely*) applied *sum* symbols are just a normal occurence, & something to get used-to.